# Is there a shortcut to search the word under cursor in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, search, keyboard-shortcuts

The functionality I'm talking about is in VI/VIM. ie. When the cursor is over the text of a word like say jiggle in command mode, press <kbd>*</kbd> to search for the next instance of jiggle. I use this all the time in VIM. Does such a shortcut exist for Xcode? or can we only double-click to highlight, <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>?

Comment: Minor clarification: do you mean _"cursor is over the text"_ or _"caret is within the text"_? (Are you talking about the mouse or the text editing insertion point?)

Comment: the text editing insertion point

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ok, Phrogz has a good solution, but I found a simpler way to do this...

To search consecutive instances of a word in Xcode:

Double-click the word you would like to find the next instance(s) of, then as Phrogz mentioned press <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> (Use Selection for Find) and then <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> (Find Next) to search for the next occurrence(s)

Comment: In "Preferences > Key Bindings > Text Key Bindings" you can map a keyboard shortcut for the "Select Word" command (same as double-click).  I use Option+UpArrow.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> will invoke the menu item "Edit All in Scope".  That will highlight all uses of the current identifier and allow you to edit all simultaneously.

Not exactly the same thing, but I find it very useful for the sort of case you're talking about.  Even if I don't need to edit an identifier, it's a nice way to quickly see all the places its used.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Similar to Cmd+D in Sublime Text

Answer (score 3):

If you select the word (⌥←,⌥⇧→) you can press <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> *(Use Selection for Find)* and then <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>  *(Find Next)* to search for the next occurrence.

Comment: I believe it is option←,option⇧→

Comment: @jenningj Oops; muscle memory doesn't translate to real memory it seems. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can combine the command+e, command+g to a shortcut

Find a file `IDETextKeyBindingSet.plist` in directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework/"

Open this file by Xcode
Add a Dictionary named `Customized` under the Root

Add a String named `Move to Next Instance` under the Customized
and set the value to `selectWord:, useSelectionForFind:, findNext:`

[IDETextKeyBindingSet.plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ixos.png)

Restart Xcode and set the Key Bindings
Find `Move to Next Instance` and set the key to `option+↓` (or other key you prefered)

[Key Bindings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h14mX.png)

Comment: Thank you, this is still relevant in Xcode 15! To edit this file, copy it to the desktop, edit, and replace the original. Changing permissions on the original file didn't work for me.
Full Path: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/

Answer (score 0):

To search a word in the currently opened file using Xcode 5 and above:

Double click the word and then

<kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>option</kbd><kbd>command</kbd> <kbd>E</kbd>

Now you can move to the next/previous instance using:

<kbd>command</kbd> <kbd>G</kbd>

or

<kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>command</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>